# Mysterious Racket error: define: unbound identifier; also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: define

Tags: lisp, racket

This program produces an error:

```
define: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: define
```

When pasted into the REPL (to be exact, the last line: (displayln (eval-clause *clause* *state*))), it works. When run in definition window, it fails. I don't know why.

```
#lang racket
(define *state* '((a false) (b true) (c true) (d false)))
(define *clause* '(a (not b) c))

(define (eval-clause clause state)
  (for ([x state])
    (eval `(define ,(first x) ,(second x))))
  (eval (cons 'or (map eval clause))))

(displayln (eval-clause *clause* *state*))
```

This too:

```
(define (eval-clause clause state)
  (eval `(let ,state ,(cons 'or clause))))
```

produces

```
let: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: let
```

This was my attempt to translate the following Common Lisp program: Common Lisp wins here?

```
; (C) 2013 KIM Taegyoon
; 3-SAT problem
; https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lisp-korea/sVajS0LEfoA
(defvar *state* '((a nil) (b t) (c t) (d nil)))
(defvar *clause* '(a (not b) c))

(defun eval-clause (clause state)
  (dolist (x state)
    (set (car x) (nth 1 x)))
  (some #'identity (mapcar #'eval clause)))

(print (eval-clause *clause* *state*))
```

And in [Paren](https://bitbucket.org/ktg/paren):

```
(set *state* (quote ((a false) (b false) (c true) (d false))))
(set *clause* (quote (a (! b) c)))
(defn eval-clause (clause state)
  (for i 0 (dec (length state)) 1
    (set x (nth i state))
    (eval (list set (nth 0 x) (nth 1 x))))  
  (eval (cons || clause)))
(eval-clause *clause* *state*)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`eval` is tricky in Racket. As per Racket Guide, 15.1.2, you need to hook into the current namespace as follows

```
(define-namespace-anchor anc)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace anc))
```

and then add `ns` to every call to `eval`:

```
(define (eval-clause clause state)
  (for ([x state])
    (eval `(define ,(first x) ,(second x)) ns))
  (eval (cons 'or (map (curryr eval ns) clause)) ns))
```

Note that this is not necessary in the REPL, as explained in the document referenced above.

However, it's probably a better idea to create a specific namespace for your definitions so that they don't get mixed up with your own module's definitions:

```
(define my-eval
  (let ((ns (make-base-namespace)))
    (lambda (expr) (eval expr ns))))

(define *state* '((a #f) (b #t) (c #t) (d #f)))
(define *clause* '(a (not b) c))

(define (eval-clause clause state)
  (for ([x state])
    (my-eval `(define ,(first x) ,(second x))))
  (my-eval (cons 'or (map my-eval clause))))

(displayln (eval-clause *clause* *state*))
```

or, if you want to continue using `true` and `false` from `racket/bool`, define `my-eval` as follows;

```
(define my-eval
  (let ((ns (make-base-namespace)))
    (parameterize ((current-namespace ns))
      (namespace-require 'racket/bool))
    (lambda (expr) (eval expr ns))))
```

Comment: Also check out my Paren Programming Language (Lisp dialect) if time permits: [Paren](https://bitbucket.org/ktg/paren)

Comment: Just waster at least one hour because of this... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would write the Common Lisp version slightly simpler:

```
(defun eval-clause (clause state)
  (loop for (var value) in state
        do (set var value))
  (some #'eval clause))
```

The LOOP form is more descriptive (since we can get rid of `CAR` and `NTH`) and `EVAL` can be directly used in the `SOME` function.

Comment: Wow! What a smart answer! [Destructuring](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node252.html)!