# evaluate an expression in Racket using eval

Tags: namespaces, eval, racket, evaluation

I want to evaluate an expression in Racket with eval. For example my expression is : (+ x 1)... but I want x to be each value from a list of values. I have tried with let but I now know the eval doesn't see the variables defined with let. I have read abut namespaces but still, I don't really know how to apply them to my problem. Thank you !

Comment: `eval` is usually the wrong answer. Can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: for `eval` have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20783438/1193075.

Comment: I have a range of values and I want to see the result of an expression for each of those values...

Comment: I suggest reading the Racket guide chapter on [reflection and dynamic evaluation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/reflection.html) and Matthew's [blog post](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html) on dynamic evaluation. Then if you're still sure you need to use `eval`, go for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```scm
> (map (lambda (n) (+ n 1)) '(2 5 3 1 99 12))
'(3 6 4 2 100 13)
```

If your expression is quoted, you could

```scm
(define ns (make-base-namespace))
(define expr '(+ x 1))
(for/list ((x '(2 5 3 1 99 12)))
  (eval `(let ((x ,x)) ,expr) ns))
=> '(3 6 4 2 100 13)
```

but I'm sure there's a better way if you provide more context.

Comment: I can't do that because my expression is quoted...'(+ x 1)

Comment: You're welcome. But I cannot stress enough that this is probably not the right solution; don't hesitate to get back to SO with more context.