# How can I generate and run random lambda expressions?

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, racket, genetic-algorithm

I am working on a school project related to genetic algorithms. I need to create an approximation algorithm where I create random lambda expressions in order to approximate the correct value, so far I am able to create random lambda expressions thanks to an example I was provided with, however, I am stuck on how to run them, here's my code:

```
#lang racket
(define operators '(+ *))
(define operands '(a b x y))

(define element
  (lambda (L)
    (list-ref L (random (length L)))))

(define expression
  (lambda (n)
    (cond ((zero? n) (element operands))
          (else
           (list
            (element operators)
            (expression (random n))
            (expression (random n)))
           ))))

;Generates lambda expression
;n is the amount of expressions 
;p is the depth of each expression
;Examples below
(define generate
  (lambda (n p)
    (if (zero? n) empty
        (cons
         (list 'λ '(x y) (expression p))
         (generate (- n 1) p))
        )))

(generate 1 1)
'((λ (x y) (* b y)))
(generate 1 3)
'((λ (x y) (* (* y y) (* y y))))
(generate 2 1)
'((λ (x y) (+ b x)) (λ (x y) (+ b x)))
(generate 2 3)
'((λ (x y) (+ (+ a y) a)) (λ (x y) (* (+ (+ y y) (* a a)) (+ (+ y x) a))))
```

Each of these generated expressions is random and it's an approximation to the correct value. How can I run these generated expressions if they are Lists?

Comment: Try `(eval (car (generate 2 3)))` to turn the first lambda into a real lambda that you can call as a function.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million Yes that is correct, I have to use _eval_  and send in the _namespace_ parameter.

Comment: So what was your question, then? That's how you run the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if we just wanted to evaluate expressions with given values for x and y, we do not need eval. A more direct would be used with *apply-formula*, however in this case we are running procedurally generated, randomized expressions so eval would be needed.

> The eval function takes a representation of an expression or definition (as a “quoted” form or syntax object) and evaluates it

Here's an example, on how to run *eval*:

```
#lang racket
(define ns (make-base-namespace))
((eval '(lambda (x y) (+ x x)) ns) 1 1)
```

*Note we are sending namespace in every eval call*

My solution would look simply like this:

```
((eval (car (generate 2 2)) ns) 1 1)
```

If you wish to test my code, modify the operands so it looks like this (Since it only validates x and y variables for now):

```
(define operands '(x y))
```

Source

- https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html
- [Mysterious Racket error: define: unbound identifier; also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778926/mysterious-racket-error-define-unbound-identifier-also-no-app-syntax-trans)
- And some help in the comments