# racket expanding a macro which is in quoted list form

Tags: macros, racket, eval

I have a macro

```
(define-syntax-rule (with tag body)
    (string-append (format "<span class=\"~s\">" 'tag)
                    body
                    (format "</span>")))

> (display (with p "some text"))
<span class="p">some text</span>
```

which is the desired result

How do I "macro-expand" **and then evaluate** the list `'(with p "some text")`? This is an example what is returned when I read a file of these forms with the intention of expanding them all.

`eval` works, but I know that's not the way to go.

I know there are a number of html-templating solutions available - but the target here is  not quite HTML - don't ask! :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racket doesn't have any built-in function like this, but it's simple to add it:

```
(define (macroexpand form)
  (syntax->datum
     (expand-to-top-form
      form)))
```

Example:

```
> (macroexpand '(with p "some text"))
'(string-append (format "<span class=\"~s\">" 'p) "some text" (format "</span>"))
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I did not know about ```expand-to-top-form```. I have edited my question (is that ok??) to add "and then evaluate" - how do I then dynamically evaluate the now-expanded macro. 
Again, thanks

Comment: @user2162871 Could you elaborate why don't you want to use `eval`?

Comment: It works for me at the interactive prompt (the interactions window of Dr Racket:  ```> (eval '(with p "foo")) => "<span class=\"p\">foo</span>"```, but not if I "run" a file which has the ```with``` macro and ```(eval '(with p "foo"))``` in it. That gives an error - 
```with: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: with``` - so I guess I don't really understand ```eval``` in Racket either ! Thanks for your help here, it's much appreciated

Comment: I have just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778926/mysterious-racket-error-define-unbound-identifier-also-no-app-syntax-trans/20783438   which might be useful... about binding a namespace when using eval...

Comment: @user2162871 Yes, that works. Add `(define-namespace-anchor anc) (define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace anc))` into your file and then you can call `(eval '(with p "some text") ns)`.